# MEAN Angular 5, Socket IO Workflow

Tags: angular, socket.io, real-time, angular5, mean

I was previously using Meteor with Angular5 which was working fairly well but I found Meteor a bit limiting. So i'm trying to refactor my app as a MEAN full stack.

I'm trying to make the interaction with the database realtime so i'm using socket.io

I've got it working but I wanted to get some opinions as to whether this is a good workflow or could I do it better?.. This is my current workflow:

jobs.component

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetJob();

    // Load all jobs currently in the database
    this._jobService.getAllJobs()
      .subscribe(jobs => {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    });

    // Append newly added jobs 
    this._jobService.getNewJobs()
      .subscribe(job => {
        this.jobs.push(job);
      })
  }
```

jobs.service

```js
  getAllJobs() {
    return this.http.get('/api/job');
  }

  getNewJobs() {
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {

      this.socket.on('jobAdded', (job: any) => {
        observer.next(job);
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };
    })
    return observable;
  }

  createJob(job) {
    this.socket.emit('add-job', job);
  }
```

index.js

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('User connected');

  // Log whenever a user disconnects
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('User disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('add-job', (job) => {
    io.emit('jobAdded', job);
    // store job in database
    db.createJob(job);
  });
});
```

Comment: Actually just thinking about this, i'm not sure how I would delete a document and have that update in realtime for all users... do i need to call my database, get all the jobs and send them to my component every time a job is created, updated or deleted? Could someone help show me how to do that?

Comment: Same flow as any other `event`. Delete a document => backend processes the request, update the database, emit an `deleteEvent` => frontend listens to that `deleteEvent` in places where you want the Jobs to be updated realtime. If a User is in that `component`, they will see the change real-time, if not, the next time they hit that component, they will see the change. Same for all of the CRUD operations

Comment: Since I’m returning an observable from my service, how could I update a single object from my collection?

Comment: Why do you have `getAllJobs()` and `getNewJobs()`? From a design standpoint, it'd be better to have your Socket just there to `emit` and `listen` to the event. When you add new Job, you'd expect an event `jobAdded` to be emitted. Why don't you, listening to that event, and re-fetching your Jobs using `getAllJobs()`? What are you going to do with the `new Job added` on the frontend?

Comment: So should I just emit an event on my socket whenever a job gets created, updated or deleted, then re-fetch all the jobs from the database and return that every time? So my jobs observable is updated every time? That just seemed a bit brute force and I was wondering if there’s another way of doing it, maybe where you only re-fetch new jobs or updated or filter the observable by deleted jobs, but maybe that’s not possible..? The new job will be added to my list of jobs in the jobs component, but I want it to appear for all users without anyone refreshing the page, am I over complicating this?

Comment: You're over complicating this. Your `getAllJobs()` will have one and only main job that is fetching the Jobs from the database. You already added/updated/deleted (modified) your Jobs collection from one of the CRUD operations, why do you want to add that to your Jobs array? I'd say just let the `getAllJobs()` does its job and you notify it when it should do its job. As I said, if a user/users are currently on the component where they should see a List of Jobs, that component will be the component where you listen to the event to trigger a `re-fetch`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so now i'm loading everything through socketIO, so whenever there is a CRUD operation I re-fetch all the jobs and return them to my job service. It seems to work but is this a good workflow? Otherwise i'm considering using Firebase..

index.js (i'll move this to a separate js file)

```
function getJobs() {
  Job.find({}, function(err, jobs) {
    if (err) { console.log('error fetching jobs'); }

    io.emit('jobs', jobs);
  });
}

function createJob(job) {
  // save the job
  Job(job).save(function(err, job) {
    if (err) { console.log('error creating job'); }

    getJobs();
  });
}

function deleteJob(jobId) {
  Job.findByIdAndRemove(jobId, function(err) {
    if (err) { console.log('error deleteing job'); }

    getJobs();
  });
}

//Socket events
io.on('connection', (socket) => {    
  socket.on('getJobs', () => {
    getJobs();
  });

  socket.on('createJob', (job) => {
    createJob(job);
  });

  socket.on('deleteJob', (jobId) => {
    deleteJob(jobId);
  });
});
```

job.service.ts

```
getAllJobs() {
  this.socket.emit('getJobs');

  let observable = new Observable(observer => {

    this.socket.on('jobs', (jobs: any[]) => {
      observer.next(jobs);
    });
    return () => {
      this.socket.disconnect();
    };
  })
  return observable;
}
```